# How to create a 'setTime' method on java in a basic clock code

Tags: java

I want to make a `setMidDay` method to Java clock, but I don't know how to. It is supposed to set the time to the middle of the day in a Java basic clock. The full code is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xPNA.png).

Comment: Please do not add code as an image. Edit this question and insert the code directly into the question. Images cannot be searched.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this

```
LocalTime midnight = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
LocalDateTime todayMidnight = LocalDateTime.of(today, midnight);
LocalDateTime tomorrowMidnight = todayMidnight.plusDays(1);

LocalTime midday = LocalTime.of(12, 0); // 12:00
```

Comment: He is trying to implement, I think, he own 'Clock' class, so while this approach is likely technically correct, I don't think it will actually help with the OP's question (no DV -- just an observation).